# How to join multiple data sets in mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, join, mapreduce

Lets say I have three datasets and I want to answer multiple questions by joining all those three datasets/files. for example if first dataset has (**id**, name) and second has (**id**,sum,**key**) and the third has (**key**, price).

How to join first and second file using **id** and in the same program how to join second and third using **key** also?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do this in the same program. To accomplish what you want to do, you have to run two map-reduce jobs.

The first map-reduce job precesses the first file and the second file which generates an output file whose format is the following -

```
id name,sum,key
```

In the above, the reducer key is "id" and the reducer value is "name,sum,key"

The second map-reduce job processes the output of the first map-reduce job and the third file which generates an output file whose format is the following -

```
id,key name,sum,price
```

In the above, the reducer key is "id,key" and the reducer value is "name,sum,price"